# Conditional filtering on multiple columns for a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with three columns, A (Dates), B (Categorical Values), and C (Actual Values).

```
A     |  B   |  C
01-19 |  5   |  0.34
01-19 |  3   |  0.25
01-19 |  7   |  0.07
01-20 |  5   |  0.15
01-20 |  2   |  0.36
```

And so on.

What I want is to filter rows according to their dates and a specific threshold - something like:

`[(01-19, x<6), (01-20, x<3)]`

In which case that'd give me

```
A     |  B   |  C
01-19 |  5   |  0.34
01-19 |  3   |  0.25
01-20 |  2   |  0.36
```

---

My solution is to set up a multi index with A and B, but then I'm not entirely sure how to filter through the B's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Idea is create dictionary of tresholds for all values of `A` column, then [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to new Series, so possible compare by `B` column and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
d = {'01-19': 6, '01-20' : 3}
df = df[df['B'] < df['A'].map(d)]
print (df)
       A  B     C
0  01-19  5  0.34
1  01-19  3  0.25
4  01-20  2  0.36
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['A'].map(d))
0    6
1    6
2    6
3    3
4    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @AlexanderCécile - I always want create the more general solutions, so my solution working if many another values in `A` - only is necessary expand dictionary by this new values.

Comment: Yeah I understood what you were doing on second glance, that’s why I deleted my previous comment. Really useful trick, I’ll have to remember that. Although I don’t see what it has to do with the size of `A`.

Comment: This is a smart use of map and dicts nice one @Jezrael

Answer (score 0):

If only two conditional you can you "and" and "or" operators like that:

```
df = df[((df['A'] == '01-19') & (df['B'] < 6)) | ((df['A'] == '01-20') & (df['B'] < 3))]
```